# Is there any reasonable and functioning fork of the Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor, deprecated, end-of-life

I've recently discovered, that GitHub is no longer maintaining the Atom Editor. The packages can no longer be installed, as this service has already been shut down.

I love the Atom Editor and I do not want to use Visual Studio Code, like suggested by GitHub (i.e. Microsoft).

Is there any reasonable and functioning fork, that will continue to work on this editor?

Comment: Try https://pulsar-edit.github.io/ or https://github.com/atom-community/atom

Answer (score 4):

As no one posted an answer so far, I will post my temporary solution.

I discovered a fork named [Pulsar](https://github.com/pulsar-edit/pulsar). This editor seems to be in an early beta stage, but it's able to install packages, although some of them still have some issues, like [PlatformIO](https://github.com/platformio/platomformio), which kind of works. But it's better than nothing.

Pulsar Editor can be downloaded at https://pulsar-edit.dev.

This question/answer is not an advertisement by any means. If someone knows a better functioning fork of the Atom Editor, please post an answer.

Comment: I'm so please to see this fork. I'm forking ecstatic!